# Printing data on click of a button in another table view controller depending upon the clicks.

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I have a table view controller which has few rows and a button infront of each row. As soon as I click on a button, the data corresponding to that button has to be displayed in another table view controller. And on simultaneous click of two buttons, the new table view controller should have data corresponding to both the rows.

However, I am not able to get the whole data. Only the latest click gets reflected in the new table view controller and a single row is printed.Please help me with this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you can schedule (with small delay 300msec) call that display "another table view controller" on first button click + add values in NSMuttableArray on ever click on some button. When time (300msec) is up you will have NSMuttableArray with data thad need to display in UITableView.

Comment: Will it work if I keep a count of the clickButtonPressed function and then send the count in cellForRowAtIndexPath in 2nd table view controller where I want data to be displayed?

Comment: Clarify me why do you need send the count in cellForRowAtIndexPath in 2nd table view controller?

Comment: there is a method in class A(connectiondidFinishLoading) which contains the data corresponding to button click and that data is being fetched by another method in class B(newFunction) and from that method the the control goes to its cellForRowatIndexPath which results in the printing of data.....connectiondidFinishLoading is called on the click of a button corresponding to each row in that view controller.And the printing should be such that if I click on two buttons, then the data corresponding to both the rows should be printed.

Comment: can you help me with the commands..I am new to objective C. :)

Answer (score 0):

For realize this you need:

1) Declare property NSMuttableArray *rowData;

2) Use one click handler for each row buttons (add code below to first TableViewController)

```
- (void) viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(rowButtonHandler:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
}

- (void) rowButtonHandler:(id)button {
    if ([rowData count])
    {
        [self performSelector:@selector(openNewTableView) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.3];
    }

    [rowData addObject:...]; // add here row data
}

- (void) openNewTableView {
    SecondTableViewController* detailViewController = [[SecondTableViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondTableViewController" bundle:nil];

    // set collected rowDatas to SecondTableViewController

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];

    [rowDatas removeAllObjects];
}
```